# what's the difference between these two ways of defining a class/object?

Tags: javascript

```
 var Foobar = function() {};

 Foobar.prototype.clickDetails = function() {
   $("#foobar").html("test");
 }

 and

 var Foobar = function () {
      return {
           clickDetails: function () {
                $("#foobar").html("test");
           }
      };
}();
```

I'm wondering because the latter is what's existing but I couldn't get it to work with Jasmine and I wrote the first one from scratch. What's the difference between the two?

Comment: Your question has basically nothing to do with jQuery. It's a question about JavaScript. I've added the relevant tag.

Comment: One needs `new`, the other not. One creates distinct functions for each object, one stores one on a prototype object. Oops, I missed that: One is a singleton, the other a constructor.

Comment: How can you have a +1 on your comment when you posted it less than 10 seconds ago ? Aussming it takes 5 seconds to read it, and another 3 seconds to determine whether it's worth a +1 and actually add it, it leaves a 2 seconds interval for someone to find it, which seems very unlikely. Would you be boosting your own comments ? :/

Comment: @Virus721: I think you're underestimating people's ability to read and assimilate. :-)

Comment: @Virus721: I +1ed it as I just edited the question for the same reason. I clicked to save edit and saw the comment. So I +1ed it immediately.

Comment: @Virus721: There are also a few "lurkers" on questions. I personally like to watch a question which I'm not quite sure yet about and if I see a comment or answer which verify my thoughts I +1 them pretty quickly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you have the `()` at the end of your second example (thank you, Bergi!), you're executing that second function immediately and storing the *result* in `Foobar`. So your first example creates a function that can be used to create objects via `new` (which can reuse a single copy of `clickDetails`), and the second creates a single non-function object.

If you *didn't* have the `()` at the end of your second example, e.g.:

```
var Foobar = function () {
      return {
           clickDetails: function () {
                $("#foobar").html("test");
           }
      };
}; // <== No () here
```

...then there would be two differences:

1. In your first example, there is only **one** `clickDetails` function which is shared by all objects created via `new Foobar()` (via the prototype chain). In your second example, a new `clickDetails` function is created by every call to `Foobar()`.
2. In your first example, you create objects via `var obj = new Foobar();` (you use the `new` keyword). In your second, just `var obj = Foobar();` (although you *can* use the `new` keyword, it has no useful effect, and is misleading).

Comment: I thought that at first, too, but actually the second one is a (disguised) IEFE.

Comment: It's misleading because the 1st returns an object inheriting from the Foobar prototype, while the 2nd just returns an object with a function on it.

Comment: @Bergi: Yeah, thanks, I saw your comment on the question and said "But it's not a singleton" until I realized...it is. :-) (I guess I managed to delete it before I made myself look like a total pratt.)

Comment: @numbers1311407: The first doesn't return an object inheriting from the `Foobar` prototype, it just returns a function. If you then use `new Foobar()`, the object returned by *that* would inherit from the `Foobar` prototype.

Comment: Yes that's what I meant.  I didn't notice the IEFE and was speaking to what I thought was the difference between `new Foobar` for both cases.